# AgendaWeek Time slots always shows default value i.e 00.00.00 (hour:minute:second)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have implemented full calendar with default view as agendaWeek. My motive here is to get date and time of clicked slot in calendar. So as an implementation I have done below code in calendar.js file:

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var now = new Date();
        var targetDate = new Date();          
        targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() + 10);
        if ((date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) < now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) || (date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) > targetDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))) {
            alert("Wrong slot of booking!!!");
        }
        else {
            console.log(date);
            alert(date.getDate()+','+ (date.getMonth()+1) +',' + date.getYear());                
        }
     },
```

So in console it shows me date correct but time is 00:00:00.
[image: Screenshot]
So it would be great if anyone help me in this issue.

Comment: the time 00:00:00 is because you're setting the time to that value via `date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` in the if part

Comment: `setHours` isn't a getter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting clicked date and time from "date" parameter and you are setting is to (0,0,0,0) through following function.

```
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Get a clone of that variable and use it to check for your conditions.

Make sure you clone that variable not just passing the reference. I hope that will solve your issue.